# sample code from chatterbot website works fine when run on spyder, but directly running the .py file doesnt

Tags: anaconda, chatterbot

i installed chatterbot the other day and was trying it out with the code provided in the website, here's the link: https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html

it worked fine on spyder but when i try to run the .py file directly it doesnt.

i am using python 3.7 with anaconda.

the initial error message i got was:

```
from _sqlite3 import *
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i then tried downloading the sqlite dll files from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and put them in the anaconda DLL folder. running the file again i got the same error for a different module:

```
from . import _mklinit
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the code from the chatterbot website.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train([
    "Hi, can I help you?",
    "Sure, I'd like to book a flight to Iceland.",
    "Your flight has been booked."
])

# Get a response to the input text 'I would like to book a flight.'
response = chatbot.get_response('I would like to book a flight.')

print(response)
```

the .py file should run normally but instead it fails to import chatterbot and shuts down immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the conda environment before running the .py file? Anaconda provides sqlite if it is declared as a dependency of an installed package. But if you haven't activated the environment, the search paths are not set correctly.

Comment: thanks for the help! if i run the script from the anaconda prompt it works, it would be more convinient if i could open the file directly from a desktop shortcut but im fine as long as it works.

Comment: @HORYKAHJEL Write a batch file that activates the conda environment, then calls the Python interpreter on your code.